# Java: Recursive sudoku solutions counting algorithm

Tags: java

I made Sudoku checker/solver with ease, but I need one that can tell wheter there is more than one solution, and couldn't wrap my head around it. I found a working algorithm, but I'm trying to understand why it's working. It's the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343214/determine-whether-a-sudoku-has-a-unique-solution), provided by @fabian

Copied below:

```
// returns 0, 1 or more than 1 depending on whether 0, 1 or more than 1 solutions are found
static byte solve(int i, int j, int[][] cells, byte count /*initailly called with 0*/) {
    if (i == 9) {
        i = 0;
        if (++j == 9)
            return 1+count;
    }
    if (cells[i][j] != 0)  // skip filled cells
        return solve(i+1,j,cells, count);
    // search for 2 solutions instead of 1
    // break, if 2 solutions are found
    for (int val = 1; val <= 9 && count < 2; ++val) {
        if (legal(i,j,val,cells)) {
            cells[i][j] = val;
            // add additional solutions
            count = solve(i+1,j,cells, count));
        }
    }
    cells[i][j] = 0; // reset on backtrack
    return count;
}
```

I tried implementing it, and as it should, it works. However though I think I understand what each *part* of the code does, I cannot get why it works.

*First*: The first `if` statement stops the method once the final number in the 2d array is reached. I get this in finding a single solution, but why does it work in finding more than one solution? Shouldn't the method just return 0+1=1 after solution is found?

*Second*: after `if (cells[i][j] != 0)` why does the recursive `solve(...)` call need `return` statement in front of it? I have made several recursive algorithms, but always by just calling the method again.

*Third*: If none suitable numbers are found the `for` loop stops and 0 is inputted to the cell place. Since it should already have 0, shouldn't the backtracking put 0 to the last place instead of current? At least that is how I made the solver that I made myself.

*Fourth*: After the backtrack set, there is just `return count`. Why is the program still working? Shouldn't it just return count = 0 and stop after facing first place that doesn't allow any numbers? Howcome there isn't a recursive call at the end?

If you made it this far on this rampling question, it is clear that I'm understanding some things completely wrong. I'd highly appreciate assistance/explanation, since using code one doesn't understand is a complete failure as far as learning to code goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so Google gracefully provided an Powerpoint lecture from Harvard:
http://www.fas.harvard.edu/~cscie119/lectures/recursion.pdf

If someone else is having problems getting recursive backtracking, I recommend checking it out. Very short but informative.

My problem seemed to be only that I stupidly (at least on hindsight) assumed for the method to stop after it calls itself recursively. I forgot that after it gets results from the recursive call it makes, it executes itself to the end. Funny how you can use umphteen hours solving something just because your initial thought process was flawed. Well, live and learn I guess.