# Convert recursive implementation to iterative implementation using stack

Tags: c, recursion, stack, sudoku, c89

I would like to write function which will count the number of possible solutions there are for a given Sudoku board.

In addition, I would like it to be implemented as an iterative solution using a stack.

I found [this recursive solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343214/determine-whether-a-sudoku-has-a-unique-solution), which is implemented in Java, and I've written it in C (it is first called with `countSolutionsRec(board, 0, 0, 0)`, where board is 2D array of integers which represents the Sudoku board game):

```
int countSolutionsRec(int board[9][9], int i, int j, int counter) {
  int value;
  if (i == 9) {
    i = 0;
    if (++j == 9){
        return 1+counter;
    }
  }
  if (board[i][j] != 0){
    return countSolutionsRec(board, i+1, j, counter);
  }
  for (value = 1; value <= 9; ++value) {
    if (validCheck(board, j, i, value)){ //This function checks if the value is a legal value to place in board[i][j] according to sudoku rules
        board[i][j]= value;
        counter = countSolutionsRec(board, i+1, j, counter);
    }
  }
  board[i][j] = 0;
  return counter;
}
```

Then, I've tried to follow [this guide](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/418776/How-to-replace-recursive-functions-using-stack-and#more) to convert the above code to an iterative implementation using a stack, and this is what I came up with:

```
int countSolutions(int board[9][9]) {

  int returnValue, value;

  SnapShotStruct newSnapshot;

  StackNode* snapshotStack;

  SnapShotStruct currentSnapshot;
  currentSnapshot.i = 0;
  currentSnapshot.j = 0;
  currentSnapshot.counter = 0;

  push(&snapshotStack, currentSnapshot);

  while (!empty(snapshotStack)) {
    currentSnapshot=top(snapshotStack);
    pop(&snapshotStack);
    if (currentSnapshot.i == 9){
        currentSnapshot.i = 0;
        if (++currentSnapshot.j == 9) {
            returnValue = currentSnapshot.counter + 1;
            continue;
        }    
    }
    if (board[currentSnapshot.i][currentSnapshot.j] != 0) {
        newSnapshot.i = currentSnapshot.i + 1;
        newSnapshot.j = currentSnapshot.j;
        newSnapshot.counter = currentSnapshot.counter;
        push(&snapshotStack, newSnapshot);
        continue;
    }
    for (value = 1; value <= 9; ++value) {
        if (validCheck(board, currentSnapshot.j, currentSnapshot.i, value)){
            board[currentSnapshot.i][currentSnapshot.j] = value;
            newSnapshot.i = currentSnapshot.i + 1;
            newSnapshot.j = currentSnapshot.j;
            newSnapshot.counter = returnValue;
            push(&snapshotStack, newSnapshot);
            continue;
        }
    }
    board[currentSnapshot.i][currentSnapshot.j] = 0;
  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

My stack implementation:

```
typedef struct SnapShotStruct {
   int i;        
   int j;
   int counter;   
   int stage;
} SnapShotStruct;

typedef struct StackNode {
  struct SnapShotStruct snapshot;
  struct StackNode* next;
} StackNode;

StackNode* newNode(SnapShotStruct snapshot) {
  StackNode* stackNode = (StackNode*) malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
  stackNode->snapshot.i = snapshot.i;
  stackNode->snapshot.j = snapshot.j;
  stackNode->snapshot.counter = snapshot.counter;
  stackNode->snapshot.stage = snapshot.stage;
  stackNode->next = NULL;
  return stackNode;
}

int empty(StackNode *root) {
  return !root;
}

void push(StackNode** root, SnapShotStruct snapshot) {
  StackNode* stackNode = newNode(snapshot);
  stackNode->next = *root;
  *root = stackNode;
}

SnapShotStruct pop(StackNode** root) {
  SnapShotStruct popped;
  StackNode* temp = *root;
  if (empty(*root))
    return popped;
  *root = (*root)->next;
  popped = temp->snapshot;
  free(temp);
  return popped;
}

SnapShotStruct top(StackNode* root) {
  SnapShotStruct snapshot;
  if (empty(root))
    return snapshot;
  snapshot = root->snapshot;
  return snapshot;
}
```

The problem is that I get wrong results from the iterative implementation.

I think the issue is the way I've converted the following line:

`counter = countSolutionsRec(board, i+1, j, counter);`

But I'm not sure how to fix it and get my iterative implementation to return the correct results.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your stack implementation don't make a lot of sense.

Comment: None of this can compile. `board` is passed as `int` to these functions, then treated as an array of arrays with subscripting operators within the functions. Also, the call to `validCheck` in the recursive function takes the expected arguments (the board, the position, and the prospect value; four arguments total), while the call in the iterative version has only three arguments (board and position).

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips to learn how to debug your code.